# Normalization of data before activation function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, activation-function

I am Altering [this tutorial](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/) to matlab where I am trying to classify to `1/0` class. each of my data points `x` is of dimension `30`, that is it has 30 features. This is my first NN.

My problem is, when I try to calculate `a1=np.tanh(z1)` or in matlab `a1 = tanh(z1);` I am getting either `1` or `-1` values since |`z1`|>2.

- Should I Normalize the values?
- Is there any promises I missed in the tutorial to stay within the -2 < z1 < 2 range?
- Am I correct in assuming it is a problem step out of boundaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input values should always be normalized, usually to the [0, 1] range. The network might not train otherwise.

Another thing that is worth noting is that you are using tanh as activation, and this function saturates at the extremes, which means zero gradient. Other activation functions like the ReLU (max(0, x)) don't have this problem. It is worth a try.

Comment: ... which is why you might consider using this form f(x) = 1.7159*tanh(2/3x), which has max of its second derivatives at +1 and -1 to avoid saturation problem (assuming normalised input).

Comment: I will try both as well as a sigmoid.

Comment: In which point should I normalize? should I normalize `X` or `z1`?